# Dynamic Routing with IDs not rendering Recent Angular Component

Tags: angular, routes, url-routing, angular-routing, angular10

I am unable to navigate to different dynamic items with IDs. To exlain :

app.component.html

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav  mode="side" opened="true">
      <mat-nav-list>
         <a mat-list-item routerLink="home" >Home</a>
         <a mat-list-item routerLink="item/1" >Item 1 </a>
         <a mat-list-item routerLink="item/2" >Item 2 </a>
         <a mat-list-item routerLink="item/3" >Item 3 </a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <div class="container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```js
export const routes = [
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
  { path: "item/:id", component: AccountsComponent }
];
```

AccountsComponent

```js
export class AccountsComponent  {
 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) {}
 public id: string;
 ngOnInit() {
 this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
 console.log("ID",this.id,"Route",this.router.url); 
   }
}
```

To check current dynamic id ,I am printing the url param in my console of AccountsComponent as above. Now if I am on route `'localhost:4200/home'` and I click on Item1, I get routed to `'localhost:4200/item/1'` and AccountsComponent loads in my sidenav, which is as expected! In my console, `ID 1 Route /item/1` is printed as well. Now If I click on Item2, route shown above is `'localhost:4200/item/2'` but my sidenavcontent i.e. AccountsComponent do not refresh!! Moreover my console shows no update i.e. `ID2` is not printed.

I noticed that since the dynamic urls do point to same Component, the router module do not load the component again. It happens very well when I move from `Home->Item1->Home->Item2` and so on because route `home` has a different component to load. See the stackblitz link below.

P.S. -

1. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sidenav-generate-nav-uuq5jc?file=src/app/accounts.component.ts) Link
2. Please do not suggest to use different components for different IDs, this is just a simpler prototype for my complex problem

Thanks:)

Comment: That's why Angular suggests to use `this.route.paramMap.pipe(switchMap` in order to get current parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your router is working fine. You should subscribe to change in route params.
Update `ngOnInit` as following

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params.id;
      console.log(params.id);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why I didn't need this when I had to switch from Home to Item1 and so on?

Comment: If You follow Home->Item1->Home->Item2->home->Item3 you will see the the expected logs.
When you try to go directly from one Item to another Item, ngOnInit is not reinvoked because you are on the same component.
In this answer, you are subscribing to route params, so whenever a change occurs in the rote params, the call back in subscribe will be called